# How to use regexp2 to match []byte data?

Tags: go

Why did it fail the first time but succeed the second time?

```
package main


import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/dlclark/regexp2"
)




func MatchPattern(patern string, data []byte) (matched bool) {
    responseStr := string(data)
    patternCompiled, err := regexp2.Compile(patern, 0)
    if err!=nil{
        fmt.Println("Compile fail")
    }
    var foundItems []string
    if x, _ := patternCompiled.FindStringMatch(responseStr); x != nil {
        groups := x.Groups()
        for i, _ := range groups {
            foundItems = append(foundItems, groups[i].String())
        }
    }
    //foundItems := m.PatternCompiled.FindStringSubmatch(responseStr)
    if len(foundItems) > 0 {
        matched = true
        return
    }
    return false
}


func main() {
    data1, _ := hex.DecodeString("1c0404e900000000000a9cad14bd4f48e7de7d3f84a8df87c54f234b71b152f3e7df4bcda8c1292ae7df4bcda8c183c3")
    data2, _ := hex.DecodeString("1c0404e900000000000a10ea14bd4f48e7df3582959b3b5ac54f234b71b152f3e7df4bcf71827088e7df4bcf7182b6ff")
    patern := "(?s)^\x1c[\x01-\x0f]..............................................$"
    fmt.Println(MatchPattern(patern, data1)) // false  
    fmt.Println(MatchPattern(patern, data2)) // true  
}
```

I want to use regexp2 to match []byte data. but as you see in the code, it returns false for data1. what can I do to make it return true?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your pattern. Update it as follows:

```
patern := "(?s)^\x1c(?:[\x01-\x0f]..){2}...........................................$"
```

This pattern expects two repetitions of a character in the range \x01 to \x0f followed by any two characters. Now both data1 and data2 should return true.

For more details on Go regex, refer to: https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/

Comment: I tried your pattern and both data1 and data2 returned false